# OpenLayers から Leaflet へ移行。　地図の緯度経度の最大値最小値をgetするには？

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

これまで [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) を使っていました。

訳あって今回、 [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) を使ってみようと思い、導入をしてみましたが、 [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) では `getExtent` 関数が使えない事がわかりました。

[公式サイトのAPI](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) を調べてみて、

```
var extent = map.getExtent().transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));

$('input[name="latmax"]').val(extent.top);
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(extent.bottom);
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(extent.right);
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(extent.left);
```

から

```
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(L.latLngBounds(getNorth()));
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(L.latLngBounds(getSouth()));
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(L.latLngBounds(getEast()));
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(L.latLngBounds(getWest()));
```

へ変更してみたのですが、`ReferenceError: getNorth is not defined`となってしまいます。
`Reference`　の使い方が間違っているは分かっているのですが、どうやったらいいのか分かりません。

どなたか教えていただけないですか？また、他の方法で構いませんので、
・表示されている地図から緯度経度の最大値最小値を取得する方法
をご存知の方どなたかご教示お願い致します。

Comment: @Hiroshi 様、わかりやすいように編集してくださりありがとうございます！^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

地図の参照が`map`の場合

```
$('input[name="latmax"]').val(map.getBounds().getNorth())
```

だと思います。`L.latLngBounds`は型ではないでしょうか。